# php not writing info to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $first = $_POST['first'];
            $last = $_POST['last'];
            $business = $_POST['business'];
            $home = $_POST['home'];
            $cell = $_POST['cell'];
            $street = $_POST['street'];
            $city = $_POST['city'];
            $state = $_POST['state'];
            $zip = $_POST['zip'];
            $system = $_POST['system'];
            $cameras = $_POST['cameras'];
            $hdd = $_POST['hdd'];

            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','rebeler_customer','callaway87');
                mysql_select_db("rebeler_customers");

                mysql_real_escape_string($first);
                $last = mysql_real_escape_string($last);
                $business = mysql_real_escape_string($business);
                $home = mysql_real_escape_string($home);
                $cell = mysql_real_escape_string($cell);
                $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
                $street = mysql_real_escape_string($street);
                $city = mysql_real_escape_string($city);
                $state = mysql_real_escape_string($state);
                $zip = mysql_real_escape_string($zip);
                $system = mysql_real_escape_string($system);
                $cameras = mysql_real_escape_string($cameras);
                $hdd = mysql_real_escape_string($hdd);

                $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `customers`(`email`,`firstname`,`lastname`, `businessname`,`homephone`, `cellphone`,`street`, `city`,`state`, `zip`,`system`, `cameras`, `hdd`) VALUES ('$email','$first','$last','$business','$home','$cell','$street','$city','$state','$zip','$system','$cameras','$hdd')");

}
?>
```

can I get some help seeing why my code is not posting the info to my db?
it connects w/ db fine just doesn't write the info to it.
let me know if you need anymore info, yall are always quick  and helpful.

Comment: When you debug this, in what way does it fail?  Is there anything useful in `mysql_error()`?  In the PHP error logs?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Can you print mysql_error()? and the value of the query.

Comment: nothing in error logs, when I run it in xampp with e_all & Strict I get a whole bund of undefined variable notifications and this one...Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\new_submit.php on line 6

Comment: @MosesBolton - where are you calling `mysql_fetch_assoc()`? It's not in the code you've given above.

Comment: You are not assigning `$first`. Also, I presume you use the parameters further down to repopulate the form? You'll need to run `htmlspecialchars()` over those values to be safe from XSS

Comment: @andrewsi, I am using that when I pull info from the database, does it also need to be in this code as well?

Comment: What did you get with a `var_dump($_POST);` before executing your query (especialy for the submit var) ?

Answer (score 2):

try this,
first echo your query and run this query to database

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `customers`(`email`,`firstname`,`lastname`, `businessname`,`homephone`, `cellphone`,`street`, `city`,`state`, `zip`,`system`, `cameras`, `hdd`) VALUES ('$email','$first','$last','$business','$home','$cell','$street','$city','$state','$zip','$system','$cameras','$hdd')";

echo $query;
//$result =mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `mysql_` to generate new code. The entire suite of functions is deprecated, and can lead to insecure code (note the giant red notice: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Instead, use PDO. An example of your code follows, using PDO. You must supply the database username, password, and database name.

```
// note: untested code follows
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
    $statement = $pdo->prepare('
        INSERT INTO `customers`(
            `email`,
            `firstname`,
            `lastname`,
            `businessname`,
            `homephone`,
            `cellphone`,
            `street`,
            `city`,
            `state`,
            `zip`,
            `system`,
            `cameras`,
            `hdd`
        ) VALUES (
            :email,
            :firstname,
            :lastname,
            :businessname,
            :homephone,
            :cellphone,
            :street,
            :city,
            :state,
            :zip,
            :system,
            :cameras,
            :hdd
        )
    ');
    $result->execute(array(
        'email'=>$_POST['email'],
        'firstname'=>$_POST['first'],
        'lastname'=>$_POST['last'],
        'businessname'=>$_POST['business'],
        'homephone'=>$_POST['home'],
        'cellphone'=>$_POST['cell'],
        'street'=>$_POST['street'],
        'city'=>$_POST['city'],
        'state'=>$_POST['state'],
        'zip'=>$_POST['zip'],
        'system'=>$_POST['system'],
        'cameras'=>$_POST['cameras'],
        'hdd'=>$_POST['hdd']
    ));
    $customer_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    if (!result || !$customer_id) {
        var_dump($pdo->errorInfo());
        die('something went wrong'); // do something better to handle errors!
    }
}
```

- `PDO` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php
- `PDO::prepare` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
- `PDOStatement::execute` - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
- `PDO::errorInfo` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php
- `PDO::lastInsertId` - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: You should try to address the question that was asked.

Comment: @TrippyD Downvotes are not for expressing your disapproval of the approach. This is a technically accurate answer, and it DOES address the question, as the code works as written, given the details of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, in theory do the same thing and is easy to debug (PHP >= 5.3):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    try {
        $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','rebeler_customer','callaway87');
        mysql_select_db("rebeler_customers");

        $fields = "email,first,last,business,home,cell,street,city,state,zip,system,cameras,hdd";

        $sql_header = '';
        $sql_values = '';
        $glue = '';

        array_filter(
            explode(',', $fields),
            function ($field) use (& $sql_header, & $sql_values, & $glue) {
                $sql_header .= $glue . '`' . $field . '`';
                $sql_values .= $glue . "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]) . "'";
                $glue = ',';
            }
        );
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `customers`($sql_header) VALUES ($sql_values)";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error in line ' . $e->getLine() . ': ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wide open for sql injection. Plus, you could do the same thing in fewer lines with `array_keys`, `array_values`, and `implode`